# Main Icon not loading in Office Web Addin because "Promise was rejected"

Tags: iis-7.5, outlook-web-addins

When I side-load the Manifest xml my add-in loads, but I notice that the Icon does not appear.  The following message appears in the debugger Console:

> The FetchEvent for "https://localhost/path/Images/MyImage_64x64.png" resulted in a network error response: the promise was rejected."

I'm not sure where to begin troubleshooting this.   I double checked that the path is correct.

**ENVIRONMENT**

- IIS 7.5 on my local machine

  The Application Pool is ASP.NET 4.0 Integrated

  I'm running Windows 7 Enterprise (64-bit)

Comment: Which Outlook client are you using to run the add-in? Are you able to load the image if you navigate to the URL directly in a web browser? If you are using Outlook on the Web (OWA), can you also check the Network log in the debugger to see the browser requested the image, and whether an error was returned?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT:  OWA is a requirement for this project and is what I'm using.   I just rebooted and started again.  I noticed the following error **Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID**.   I'm guessing this is about a certificate.   I'm using the certificate I created with IIS.  I guess I should check it again.

Comment: Yes it seems to be an issue with the certificate, kindly check that again. Is the issue still occurring ?

Comment: It ended up being a certificate issue.   We put my code on a Dev server with a "good" certificate and everything went through just fine.